# Getting more screen space/area in firefox

Tags: firefox

One thing that I dont like in firefox is how much space the various bars waste:

In the attached screenshot, I would like to:

1) Hide the topmost bar which shows the complete page title (Region **A** in the pic). The "minimize/maximize/close" buttons (Region **C**) could move in the same bar as the bar with the "Fire/Edit......." buttons/

2) Below the URL entry form, there were some bookmarks. I deleted the bookmarks, but couldn't reclaim the space (Region **B**)

I know, one alternative would be full screen mode, but I kind of want the "url entry, main buttons and the tab buttons"

Can anyone suggest me how to do this, even if partially?

[image]

Comment: Can you post the image instead of a link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In full screen mode, F11 key, you actually keep seing the tabs (at least in Firefox 3.6) , and the url entry field. Move over there the cursor, and it shows and hides if move it over. If want it fixed there always, just right click in any empty space in the top area -not in the white url field- and uncheck "Hide Toolbar". Full screen would remove window title bar. To remove (B) just go to "View" Menu, Toolbars, uncheck  Bookmarks toolbar.

Edit: Cross posting, did not see db answer.

Comment: thanks, except for having the back/refresh/file/menu buttons, this does everything ...

Comment: Glad it worked :)

Answer (score 6):

Blame your window manager for 1)

Firefox 4 looks promising in that regard, but I haven't used it yet.

---

2) *View » Toolbars » Bookmarks Toolbar*

---

In the same menu, select *Customize*. Then you can drag address bar and buttons to the right of the menus. Disable *Navigation Toolbar* afterwards:

[image]

Comment: Regarding the titlebar, you might have some luck with javascript popups that set `fullscreen=1` but don't actually take up the full screen. I think it removes (or requires removing) all other menubars though.

Comment: thanks, with this, now only titlebar remains for which i will try more on google.

Comment: Just as a disclaimer: I downvoted none of the other answers.

Answer (score 1):

Use Firefox 4. I have some limitations in my little screen and using Firefox 4 helped me a lot.

Comment: Hey, why -2? Firefox 4 uses tabs "inside" titlebar, so you can have more free vertical space!

Comment: Disagree with the -2 too. FF4b11 works fine for me too. The question doesn't specifically state a FF version.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up installing FF4b11 after reading another post regarding hiding titlebar. It certainly has the features I am looking for.

Comment: I'm not quite sure about the downvotes either. I suspect because you're suggesting using a different software (even if just the beta of the next version) to solve an issue with the currently used program, or for repeating (with more authority at least) what I wrote in my answer. +1 for the first-hand experience.

Comment: Well, you can use FF 3.6 + (Tabs on Top + Hide Caption Titlebar Plus).addons = FF 4 appearance

Answer (score 0):

[TinyMenu](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/tiny-menu/) (have all the menus contained in one) and [Omnibar](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/omnibar/) (to combine the search and address fields) would maximise space. [AutoHideStatusBar](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/autohidestatusbar/) would minimise down the bottom too.

EDIT: You may also be interested in [foxiFrame basic](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/foxiframe-basic/) and [HideFindBar](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/hide-find-bar/) too. Disclaimer to pedants: these *suggestions* might not suit you.

Comment: The don't reduce vertical height.

Comment: @Daniel Beck: Tiny Menu and AutoHideStatusBar do.

Comment: Thanks, omnibar seems useful, and I think recent ff versions have option to show/hide statusbar

Comment: @Bobby In my answer I added a screenshot with everything on a single line, without these extensions. So how would they help me further?

Comment: @anon You can hide the status bar, but then it remains hidden. The extension displays it again when you e.g. hover over a link to display the target URL, similar to what Chrome does.